# Android distance are wrong

Tags: android, google-maps

```
lat = 6.92961234
lng = 79.84796614

lat1 = 6.85620511
lng1 = 79.91251376 

Location locationA = new Location("point A");

locationA.setLatitude(lat);
locationA.setLongitude(lng);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");

locationB.setLatitude(lati);
locationB.setLongitude(lngi);

double distancei = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

String cc = Double.toString(distancei);

float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(lati / 1E6, lngi / 1E6, lat / 1E6, lng / 1E6,results);
float s = results[0] * 0.000621371192f;
String a2 = Float.toString(s);
```

Two methods gives me Different answers as well as **BOTH SEEMS TO BE WRONG**.. since i looked at the google maps and the answers it shows about 14km(around 8mils). But the answers are showing as 6point smthing. and i dont know its on meters/km/miles.

please help me out... thank you

Comment: where the part where u geocode the long and lat in ur code /

Comment: From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html: "´distanceBetween(...)`
Computes the approximate distance *in meters* between two locations, and *optionally the initial and final bearings* of the shortest path between them." Maybe the result you're looking at is one of the optional results?

Comment: And what kind of conversion are you doing in the second last line, where you multiply the result with 0.000621...?

Comment: @user1469168 do i have to lat/1E6 on the distanceto part as well??

Comment: @Treb i tried to convert it to km... i just found something from net and tried

i want to get the Km distance from the current point(lat = 6.92961234 lng = 79.84796614) to the point i derive from server(lat1 = 6.85620511 lng1 = 79.91251376 )

Comment: Well, since your result is in meters, you should convert it into km by dividing by 1000.

Comment: What is lati/lngi? You have defined lat1/lng1 in your sample (number one not letter 'i')

Comment: Still its wrong :( thats the problem... Just try adding these cordinates on the gmaps...(6.92397468,79.85448202||6.92961234,79.84796614)it will show you about 1.9km difference but with the above code it shows 0.00515....something

Comment: @NickT yah since it derives from the server i did not put that code here i just added lat n lat1 sorry for the mistake... but the problem is still the same

Comment: as i said its a mistake i did while typing the question

Answer (score 1):

If you had taken the trouble to produce some code which compiled and ran, read the javadocs and had run the following corrected code through the debugger:

```
private void test() {

    double lat = 6.92961234;
    double lng = 79.84796614;

    double lati = 6.85620511;
    double lngi = 79.91251376;

    Location locationA = new Location("point A");
    locationA.setLatitude(lat);
    locationA.setLongitude(lng);
    Location locationB = new Location("point B");
    locationB.setLatitude(lati);
    locationB.setLongitude(lngi);

    double distancei = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
    float[] results = new float[3];
    Location.distanceBetween(lati, lngi, lat, lng,  results);
    // Distance in metres is in results[0]
}
```

You would see that both distancei and results[0] give you the same answer which is 10807 metres. This seems about right to me.